# Issue with threaded queue implementation in .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, mono

I'm trying to implement a threaded queue in .NET, but I'm having some trouble when I run it through tests.

The implementation is permitted to forego some of the complexities with threading as it enforces that only one thread will ever place items into the queue and only one thread will ever take them out (this is by design).

The problem is that sometimes, the Take() will skip an item as if it was never there and in my tests I'll get "Expected: 736 But was: 737".  I can't see anywhere in this code that that kind of effect would occur; Put will only ever place after the very last item (so it shouldn't be affecting this.m_Head directly) and Take is using Interlocked.Exchange to take the item from the head.

How does this implementation permit the issue to occur?

**Implementation:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

#pragma warning disable 420

namespace Tychaia.Threading
{
    public class TaskPipeline<T>
    {
        private int? m_InputThread;
        private int? m_OutputThread;
        private volatile TaskPipelineEntry<T> m_Head;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new TaskPipeline with the current thread being
        /// considered to be the input side of the pipeline.  The
        /// output thread should call Connect().
        /// </summary>
        public TaskPipeline()
        {
            this.m_InputThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            this.m_OutputThread = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Connects the current thread as the output of the pipeline.
        /// </summary>
        public void Connect()
        {
            if (this.m_OutputThread != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("TaskPipeline can only have one output thread connected.");
            this.m_OutputThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Puts an item into the queue to be processed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value.</param>
        public void Put(T value)
        {
            if (this.m_InputThread != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Only the input thread may place items into TaskPipeline.");

            // Walk the queued items until we find one that
            // has Next set to null.
            var head = this.m_Head;
            while (head != null)
            {
                if (head.Next != null)
                    head = head.Next;
                if (head.Next == null)
                    break;
            }
            if (head == null)
                this.m_Head = new TaskPipelineEntry<T> { Value = value };
            else
                head.Next = new TaskPipelineEntry<T> { Value = value };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes the next item from the pipeline, or blocks until an item
        /// is recieved.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The next item.</returns>
        public T Take()
        {
            if (this.m_OutputThread != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Only the output thread may retrieve items from TaskPipeline.");

            // Wait until there is an item to take.
            var spin = new SpinWait();
            while (this.m_Head == null)
                spin.SpinOnce();

            // Return the item and exchange the current head with
            // the next item, all in an atomic operation.
            return Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_Head, this.m_Head.Next).Value;
        }
    }
}

#pragma warning restore 420
```

**Failing Test:**

```
[Test]
public void TestPipelineParallelTo100()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var pipeline = new TaskPipeline<int>();
    var success = true;
    int expected = 0, actual = 0;
    ThreadStart processor = () =>
    {
        pipeline.Connect();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var v = pipeline.Take();
            if (v != i)
            {
                success = false;
                expected = i;
                actual = v;
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 10));
        }
    };
    var thread = new Thread(processor);
    thread.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pipeline.Put(i);
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 10));
    }
    thread.Join();
    if (!success)
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this for research purposes? If not, you might be better off using a `ConcurrentQueue` or a `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: Any specific reason to build your own (and not use ConcurrentQueuue) ?

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue` is buggy under Mono (I can put an object created with `new` into a `ConcurrentQueue` in Mono and pull out null on another thread).  So I need my own implementation that doesn't exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Show code for the `TaskPipelineEntry<T>` I suspect the `Next` property isn't synchronizing properly.

Comment: Surely your implementation can have one thread modifying the linked list to add items while another thread removes them, with no synchronisation between them?

Comment: @Romoku Next is just a field of type `TaskPipelineEntry<T>`.  It has no special semantics.

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue` is a non-blocking queue. Are you sure the `TryDequeue` method can set the out parameter `result` to `null` *and* return `true` from the method? Both values returned by `TryDequeue` are critical pieces of information here.

Comment: @280Z28 Yes, I'm sure.  It returns true from the method, and the variable it stores the result in is null.  The implementation is from https://github.com/hach-que/Tychaia/blob/lightspeed/Tychaia/Generators/ChunkProvider.cs#L163 onwards, and as you can see, the only thing that stores values into m_Tasks is the result straight from a new call, yet line 221 can have `rt` as null.

Comment: @MatthewWatson 1) No, you can't.  This is particularly true when the list is small.  If you only have 0 or 1 items in the queue then adding/removing an item at the same time can very easily result in the list getting corrupted.  It needs less synchronization, but not none. 2) Linked lists have pretty horrible performance.  Having an array backed queue will generally perform better, even with the synchronization needed.

Comment: @280Z28 In addition, it's not a problem at all in .NET (it runs fine).  Only under Mono is the issue present, which leads me to think it's an issue in their implementation.

Comment: @Servy: That's what I meant: That unsynchronized cross-thread variable access could be happening, and that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oh, in that case, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign the value of `m_Head.Next` after it is read in `Take` for passing to `Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_Head, this.m_Head.Next)`, the pointer will be lost because the only way to access it was through `m_Head`.

- `Take` reads `m_Head.Next` (`==null`)
- `Put` writes `m_Head.Next` (`!=null`)
- `Take` writes `m_Head` (`==null`)

**Edit:** This should work. I used a non-null sentinel value and `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to make sure `Put` doesn't try to reuse an entry that `Take` is already removing.

**Edit 2:** Tweaks to `Take`.

**Edit 3:** I believe I still need to add a `goto retry;` in `Put` if the identified tail is `Entry.Sentinel`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

#pragma warning disable 420

namespace Tychaia.Threading
{
    public class TaskPipeline<T>
    {
        private int? m_InputThread;
        private int? m_OutputThread;
        private volatile Entry m_Head;

        private sealed class Entry
        {
            public static readonly Entry Sentinel = new Entry(default(T));

            public readonly T Value;
            public Entry Next;

            public Entry(T value)
            {
                Value = value;
                Next = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new TaskPipeline with the current thread being
        /// considered to be the input side of the pipeline.  The
        /// output thread should call Connect().
        /// </summary>
        public TaskPipeline()
        {
            this.m_InputThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            this.m_OutputThread = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Connects the current thread as the output of the pipeline.
        /// </summary>
        public void Connect()
        {
            if (this.m_OutputThread != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("TaskPipeline can only have one output thread connected.");
            this.m_OutputThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Puts an item into the queue to be processed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value.</param>
        public void Put(T value)
        {
            if (this.m_InputThread != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Only the input thread may place items into TaskPipeline.");

        retry:
            // Walk the queued items until we find one that
            // has Next set to null.
            var head = this.m_Head;
            while (head != null)
            {
                if (head.Next != null)
                    head = head.Next;
                if (head.Next == null)
                    break;
            }

            if (head == null)
            {
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_Head, new Entry(value), null) != null)
                    goto retry;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref head.Next, new Entry(value), null) != null)
                    goto retry;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes the next item from the pipeline, or blocks until an item
        /// is recieved.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The next item.</returns>
        public T Take()
        {
            if (this.m_OutputThread != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Only the output thread may retrieve items from TaskPipeline.");

            // Wait until there is an item to take.
            var spin = new SpinWait();
            while (this.m_Head == null)
                spin.SpinOnce();

            // Return the item and exchange the current head with
            // the next item, all in an atomic operation.
            Entry head = m_Head;
        retry:
            Entry next = head.Next;
            // replace m_Head.Next with a non-null sentinel to ensure Put won't try to reuse it
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref head.Next, Entry.Sentinel, next) != next)
                goto retry;

            m_Head = next;
            return head.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh so when `Put` sets the `Next` property in the `else` clause, and then the `head` disappears because it's pointing directly to `m_Head`?

Comment: Yes, the `else` part of `Put` is the problem location in that method - specifically when the local variable `head` in that method is the previously used `m_Head` that `Take` is about to discard.

Comment: Is there any way around this without using locks?  I can't see how to represent the complex logic of traversing the linked list by only using `Interlocked`.

Comment: Took me a few moments to work it out, but the code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee722114(v=vs.100).aspx makes sense for it's `Put` operation.  Effectively the `CompareExchange` ensures that it doesn't set the value if it's changed between the `head = m_head` line and the `Interlocked.CompareExchange`.

Comment: @Hach-Que see Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott's [Lock-free queue](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/podc-1996.pdf) paper for an example. Warning, though -- it is _scalable_ but it is also _slow_ if you don't have a wicked amount of contention. .NET's `ConcurrentQueue` will be more suitable for most people.

Comment: Also if you read that paper, they use ABA-tagged pointers. You can skip that and just use plain references because garbage collection solves the ABA problem.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the implementation on the MSDN page works when you want to put items where head is; not when you want to put items after head, which is what I need to do.

Comment: @Hach-Que Don't be so afraid to use `lock()` , it is usually very efficient. And a lot easier to get right than lock-free algos.

Comment: @Hach-Que I haven't run the code, but I have updated it to use a slightly different mechanism for updating `m_Head` and `Next` that should get you going again.

Comment: @HenkHolterman but concurrent algorithms are so much more fun!

Comment: Only when you think _"sometimes, the Take() will skip an item"_ is fun.

Comment: I don't see where `Put` is handling the existence of the sentinel.  Won't this code permit `Put` to append something on the end of the sentinel, because it treats it like any other value in the queue / pipeline?

Comment: Oh I see, `if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_Head, new Entry(value), null) != null)` ensures that it won't set the variable unless it still has `null` in it; if it changed in the meantime it rescans the queue.

Comment: @Hach-Que You may be correct about appending to the sentinel. I'll review this afternoon.